# How to update my sql table with out page refresh in php?

Tags: php, mysql, page-refresh

Hi i want to update my sql table field without page refresh in php how can  i achieve i tried but my code is not working  i do not know where i am wrong

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('#myForm').on('submit',function(e) {

    $.ajax({
        url:'assignlead.php',
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        type:'POST',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        $("#success").show().fadeOut(5000);
        },
        error:function(data){
            $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000);
        }
        });
e.preventDefault();
});
});
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
include('conn.php');
$per_page = 3; 
if($_GET)
{
$page=$_GET['page'];
}
$start = ($page-1)*$per_page;
$select_table = "select * from clientreg order by id limit $start,$per_page";
$variable = mysql_query($select_table);
?>
<form class="form2" action="" method="POST" name="myForm" id="myForm">
<div style="width:100%;">
<?php
        $i=1;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($variable))
        {
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" >
  <?php
        }
?>
<div class="buttons"> <span id="error" style="display:none; color:#F00">Some Error!Please Fill form Properly </span> <span id="success" style="display:none; color:#0C0">All the records are submitted!</span>
        <input class="greybutton" type="submit" value="Send" />
      </div>

<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM login where  role=1");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

?>

<input type="checkbox" name="eid[]" value="<?php echo $row["eid"]; ?>" ><?php echo $row["username"]; ?>
<?php
}
?>
</div>

    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**assignlead.php**

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
mysql_select_db("helixcrm",$conn);
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"]!="") {
$usersCount = count($_POST["id"]);
for($i=0;$i<$usersCount;$i++) {
mysql_query("UPDATE clientreg set eid='" . $_POST["eid"][$i] .  "'  WHERE id='" . $_POST["id"][$i] . "'");
}
}
?>
<?php
$rowCount = count($_POST["users"]);
for($i=0;$i<$rowCount;$i++) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clientreg WHERE Id='" . $_POST["users"][$i] . "'");
$row[$i]= mysql_fetch_array($result);
$id=$row[$i]['id'];
?>
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $row[$i]['id']; ?>"></td>
<?php
$rowCoun = count($_POST["eid"]);
for($j=0;$j<$rowCoun;$j++) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE eid='" . $_POST["eid"][$j] . "'");
$row[$j]= mysql_fetch_array($result);
$eid=$row[$j]['eid'];
?>
<input type="hidden" name="eid[]" class="txtField" value="<?php echo $row[$j]['eid']; ?>">
<?php
}
}
?>
```

i tried a lot but i am not able to get my output

How can i achieve my output

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to use ajax.

Comment: SQL Injection spotted... use `prepared statements` with either MySQLi or PDO ;S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your javascript like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : 'assignlead.php',
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            type : 'POST',
            success : function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $("#success").show().fadeOut(5000);
            },
            error:function(data){
                $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000);
            }
        });
        // !important for ajax form submit
        return false;
    });
});
```